# Как раскрыть Cisco ASDM на локальной машине

Tags: cisco

Не моги бы пожалуйста подсказать такой момент. Возможно ли раскрыть Cisco ASA ASDM на GNS3 на локальной машине? Если  это возможно то подскажи как? Либо видео либо мануал так как сколько я не смотрел и не пытался у меня не получается сделать данную задачу.
Возможно можно это сделать на UNetLab? если да то подскажите как